# Question about understanding Inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

Inner product is a pairing that takes two vectors $\mathbf V, \mathbf W$ and produces a real number $\langle\mathbf V; \mathbf W \rangle$. 
I have a formula $\langle Y_n -\hat{Y_n^*},X_n^j\rangle,j=1,\ldots,n$, where $X_n^j$ is the $j$th column of matrix X, $Y_n$ and $\hat{Y_n^*}$ are vectors, does it mean inner product?
If it is inner product, $\langle Y_n -\hat{Y_n^*},X_n^j \rangle=X_n^T (Y_n-\hat{Y_n^*})$ is correct or not?

Comment: I changed $<\mathbf V; \mathbf W >$ to $\langle\mathbf V; \mathbf W \rangle$, and I was uncertain whether you intended $\{X_n^j\}$ or $X_n^j$.  You had it enclosed in {curly braces}, and sometimes people do that when they intend those braces to be visible (and that doesn't work without backslashes in the code), but sometimes they do it inadvertently as a result of software said to be on the web somewhere that writes their MathJax code for them. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that notation probably means an inner product of a vector and a matrix column.

An inner product can be interpreted as the (matrix) product of a $1 \times n$ matrix and a $n \times 1$ matrix. This isn't quite correct because the inner product gives you a real number whereas the matrix product gives you a $ 1 \times 1$ matrix. But, close enough.

So, if you think of a vector as a column (a $n \times 1$ matrix), then
$$
\langle U, V \rangle = U^T * V =V^T * U
$$
where the "$*$" denotes an ordinary matrix product.

Your transpose formula is not quite correct. On the right-hand side, you need to use the $j$-th row of $X^T$, and you have to interpret the vector as a $n \times 1$ matrix (i.e. as a column).

Comment: If matrix X is not a $1 \times n$ matrix, $X_n^j$ is one column of matrix X, is the equation right? I know on the right-hand side I should use jth row of $X^T$, but in my reference, it just use $X^T$. What should I understand it?

Comment: The notation used in your book is horrible. They don't seem to have a way to write a row of a matrix, only a column. So, with their notation, it seems impossible to write the correct formula. It sounds like your understanding is correct, so I don't think you should worry about the silly notation in your book.

Comment: I discussed with my supervisor, and he agreed that the notation is wrong. Thanks again. You make me more confident about discussing the mistakes in my reference.